# How to deal with null values in spark reduceByKey function?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, null, apache-spark-sql

I have a spark DataFrame (df) which looks like this:

```
+----------+--------+----------+--------+                                                                 
|        c1|      c2|        c3|      c4|
+----------+--------+----------+--------+
|      1   |    5   |      null|    7   |
+----------+--------+----------+--------+
|      1   |    5   |      4   |    8   |
+----------+--------+----------+--------+
|      1   |    3   |      null|   11   |
+----------+--------+----------+--------+
|      1   |    3   |      null| null   |
+----------+--------+----------+--------+
|      2   |    6   |      23  |   17   |
+----------+--------+----------+--------+
|      2   |    6   |      7   |    3   |
+----------+--------+----------+--------+
|      2   |    3   |      null|   11   |
+----------+--------+----------+--------+
|      2   |    3   |      null|   17   |
+----------+--------+----------+--------+
```

I want to aggregate using `(c1,c2)` as key and have `average` of `c3` and `c4`, so that I have this:

```
+----------+--------+----------+--------+                                                                 
|        c1|      c2|        c3|      c4|
+----------+--------+----------+--------+
|      1   |    5   |      4   |  7.5   |
+----------+--------+----------+--------+
|      1   |    3   |      null|   11   |
+----------+--------+----------+--------+
|      2   |    6   |      15  |    10  |
+----------+--------+----------+--------+
|      2   |    3   |      null|   14   |
+----------+--------+----------+--------+
```

So, essentially I am ignoring the `null` values.

My *half-baked* code looks something like this:

```
val df1 = df.
          // just working on c3 for time being
          map(x => ((x.getInt(0), x.getInt(1)), x.getDouble(3))).
          reduceByKey( 
            (x, y) => {
            var temp = 0
            var sum = 0.0
            var flag = false
            if (x == null) {
              if (y != null) {
                temp = temp + 1
                sum = y
                flag = true
              }
            } else {
              if (y == null) {
                temp = temp + 1
                sum = x 
              } else {
                temp = temp + 1
                sum = x + y
                flag = true
              } 
            } 
            if (flag == false) {
              null 
            } else {
              sum/temp 
            }
            }
          )
```

Obviously, the above code is not working. Any help to make the code work is very much appreciated.

**Edit 1** The answer given by @zero232 is a solution. However, it is not "the solution" I am looking for. My interest was to understand *how to deal with null values when writing a custom function for `reduceByKey()`*. **I am re-asking the question below**:

I want to aggregate using `(c1,c2)` as key and have `root mean square` [{sum(a_i^2)}^0.5] (or some function which is not available in spark for that matter) of `c3` and `c4` while ignoring the null values, so that I have this:

```
+----------+--------+----------+--------+                                                                 
|        c1|      c2|        c3|      c4|
+----------+--------+----------+--------+
|      1   |    5   |      4   | 10.63  |
+----------+--------+----------+--------+
|      1   |    3   |      null|   11   |
+----------+--------+----------+--------+
|      2   |    6   |   24.04  |  17.26 |
+----------+--------+----------+--------+
|      2   |    3   |      null| 20.24  |
+----------+--------+----------+--------+
```

Comment: You can simplify your code a lot changing this: `x.getInt(1)` to this: `if (x.isNullAt(1)) 0 else x.getInt(1)`. In other words, just map `null` to `0`.

Comment: @DavidGriffin,but what if all the values are `null`. I would get 0 instead of `null`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just `groupBy` and use `mean`:

```
df.groupBy("c1", "c2").mean("c3", "c4")
```

or `agg`

```
df.groupBy("c1", "c2").agg(avg("c3"), avg("c4"))
```

Typically all primitive functions on `DataFrames` will handle correctly `null` values.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

def rms(c: String) = sqrt(avg(pow(col(c), 2))).alias(s"rms($c)")
df.groupBy("c1", "c2").agg(rms("c3"), rms("c4"))
```

If you want to ignore `null` with `RDDs` just filter these out before you apply reduction:

```
somePairRDD.filter(_._2 != null)
  .foldByKey(someDefualtValue)(someReducingFunction)
```

or convert values to `Option` and use pattern matching:

```
somePairRDD.mapValues(Option(_)).reduceByKey {
  case (Some(x), Some(y)) => doSomething(x, y)
  case (Some(x), _) => doSomething(x)
  case (_, Some(_)) => doSomething(y)
  case _ => someDefualt
}
```

or use `map` / `flatMap` / `getOrElse` and other standard tools to handle undefined values.