# Null Pointer exception in Map function of Spark program

Tags: scala, dictionary, apache-spark, nullpointerexception

I am new to Scala, while running one spark program I am getting null Pointer exception. Can anyone point me how to solve this.

```
val data = spark.read.csv("C:\\File\\Path.csv").rdd

val result = data.map{ line => {
  val population  = line.getString(10).replaceAll(",","")
   var popNum = 0L
    if (population.length()> 0)

     popNum = Long.parseLong(population)
     (popNum, line.getString(0))

   }}

.sortByKey(false)
.first()

//spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(result)).saveAsTextFile(args(1))

println("The result is: "+ result)

spark.stop
```

Error message :

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at com.nfs.WBI.KPI01.HighestUrbanPopulation$$anonfun$1.apply(HighestUrbanPopulation.scala:23)
>       at com.nfs.WBI.KPI01.HighestUrbanPopulation$$anonfun$1.apply(HighestUrbanPopulation.scala:22)
>       at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:410)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that in your input data there is at least one row that does not contain a value in column 10, so that `line.getString(10)` returns `null`. When calling `replaceAll(",","")` on that result, the NullPointerException occurs.

A quick fix would be to wrap the the call to `getString` in an `Option`:

```scala
val population = Option(line.getString(10)).getOrElse("")
```

This returns the value of column 10 or an empty string if the column is `null`.

Some care must be taken when parsing the long. Unless you are absolutely sure that the column always contains a number, a `NumberFormatException` could be thrown.

In general, you should check the [inferSchema option](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameReader.html#csv(scala.collection.Seq)) of the CSV reader of Spark and try to avoid parsing the data yourself.

Comment: Thanks a ton @werner. It worked. I have gone through the inferSchema option of the CSV reader suggested by you, will try it once I am through with some basics.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the parsing issues mentioned elsewhere in this post, it seems that you have numbers separated by commas in your data. This is going to complicate csv parsing and cause potentially undesirable behavior. You may have to sanitize the data even before reading in spark.

Also if you're using Spark 2.0, it's best to use Dataframes/Datasets along with GroupBy constructs. See this post - [How to deal with null values in spark reduceByKey function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36295723/how-to-deal-with-null-values-in-spark-reducebykey-function). I suspect you have null values in your sort key as well.